# Get a non- duplicate result through sql query

Tags: php, sql, database

Sorry bout the confusion this is what I am asking. I am trying to send videos to an ftp server but I do not want the videos that already exist on the ftp to be re uploaded. Hence i need a way to tell the database to do that. What I have is below, made a change thanks to @neo but it still returns and invalid query.

```
<?php

$dest="/Tools";


$query = "SELECT videoid AS videoId FROM videos 
WHERE channel = 62 AND videoid NOT IN (@videoId)";


$results = mysql_query($query);

$server=("ftp.//");

$connect=ftp_connect($server);

$login_result=ftp_login($connect,"","");

if(!(login_result)||!($connect))
{
$error;
}
else
{
echo "success";
}


if (!$result) {
    $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    die($message);
}


while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // loop through every videoid returned, ftp each individually
$upload=ftp_put($connect,$dest,$row['videoid'],FTP_BINARY);
if (!upload)
{
echo "failed to upload $results\n";
}

else{
echo "successfully uploaded $videoid";
}

ftp_close($connect);

}
mysql_free_result($result);





?>
```

Comment: Please provide some example data (a few rows) from each table to clarify what you are asking.

Comment: What's the desired result of that query? It's unclear what do you want to get.

Comment: <quote>which automatically has each 'shoeid' that was created in the "shoes" table</quote> ???????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SELECT shoes.shoeid AS shoeId FROM shoes WHERE color = RED AND shoes.shoeid NOT IN (@shoeID);

Where @shoeID is a comma separated list of shoe ids that are already been uploaded into the FTP location

Comment: neo please take a look at my edit. I have included what you advised but it returns an invalid query with a blank mysql_error message. When I check the ftp, no videos have been uploaded neither.

Comment: question neo. I got my bugs fixed but It doesn't upload the vids still. Do i have to create a variable "@shoeid" within the code and reference it to my destination on the ftp. Like so: @shoeid="ftp..."?

Comment: Hi, @videoId should be a commaseparated list of all the videos that are in the FTP server. EG:@videoId = 1,2,3,4 where 1,2,3,4 are the ids of the Videos that are already in the FTP server. But a better approach will be, as I suggested earlier, to have a flag in the DB to mark if the video is already uploaded or not!!! Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like :

```
SELECT shoes.shoeid AS shoeId, sox.shoeid AS soxId
FROM shoes, sox
WHERE color = RED AND sox.shoeid = shoes.shoeid;
```

That would return the field with their new alias : `shoeId` and `soxId`

NOTE : That is built on the MySQL logic. It should work on other sql engine, but not tested.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. That is not what i want, my goal is to get a result so i can send that result to an ftp but i dont want to repeat the shoes that have been already uploaded in the ftp before. Thats why i need a way to validate. Sorry i wasn't clear enough. I might not even need the sox table now that I think about it. I just need to know which shoe has not yet been uploaded into the ftp. Thanks

Comment: Is there a flag in your DB to indicate which all shoes were already ftp'ed?

Comment: no there isn't is there a way i can do that without altering the database?

Comment: Then you may need to send the list of uploaded shoe id as a parameter and try a query like this: SELECT shoes.shoeid AS shoeId FROM shoes WHERE color = RED AND shoes.shoeid NOT IN (@shoeID);

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the list of Shoes which has already been uploaded to server.

Either put a flag in db as said be "Neo" else traverse through all the shoes on FTP server and then get it passed to db. Though the latter is not recommended at all.